# How to Modify JSON Column With Data From Another Column in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, json

I have table ratingperiods. Lets say for sake of simplicity that it consists of three columns:

```
create table ratingperiods
(
    Id              binary(16)                not null            primary key,
    EndDate         date                      not null,
    Settings        json                      null,
);
```

Settings is filled with text:

```
{"ProductRating": {}}
```

and I want to add new property to it to make it look like this:

```
{"ProductRating": {"EndOfAppealPeriod": "2022-02-11T06:10:00Z"}}
```

To do so, I want to use data from EndDate column and add to it 4 days and 9 hours.
I wrote query like this:

```
update ratingperiods
set Settings =
        JSON_SET(`Settings`, '{
          "ProductRating": {
            "EndOfAppealPeriod": "Somehow EndDate + 4 days and 9 hours"
          }
        }');
```

The main problem is that I don't know how to reference EndDate column in set statement. How to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql query for finding date of 4days after current date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33396307/mysql-query-for-finding-date-of-4days-after-current-date)

Comment: No, as I wrote in question the main problem is that I don't know how to reference EndDate column in JSON_SET statement

Comment: *Somehow EndDate + 4 days and 9 hours* `EndDate + INTERVAL '4 9' DAY_HOUR`  or `EndDate + INTERVAL 4 DAY + INTERVAL 9 HOUR`. For to insert this value into the string literal use CONCAT() function. And, because of you want custam datetime format, apply DATE_FORMAT() function with proper formatting pattern.

Comment: Guys, maybe it somehow slipped from you attention, but MAIN PROBLEM IS NOT ABOUT ADDING 4 DAYS AND 9 HOURS TO EndDate. The main problem is to reference column in string
'{
          "ProductRating": {
            "EndOfAppealPeriod": "EndDate"
          }
        }'

Comment: this is a string and i need to reference column in this string

Comment: ?? I have said - use CONCAT(). The value provided to JSON_SET as a value to be inserted is string literal.

Comment: Would you like to post as answer?

Comment: PS. Your JSON_SET usage seems to be incorrect. It must have at least 3 arguments - altered JSON document, path and new value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE ratingperiods
SET Settings = JSON_SET(Settings, 
                        '$.ProductRating.EndOfAppealPeriod',
                        DATE_FORMAT(EndDate + INTERVAL '4 9' DAY_HOUR, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%sZ'));
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=401821393570bffbae1e593741f134f8